# How cast TabItem by key to read ChildNames

Tags: c#, wpf

I add `TabItem` to `TabControl x:Name="TabCards"`

```
private string AddTabItemForCard(string cardName)
    {
        var availableAddress = CheckWithAddressIsFree(cardName);
        if (availableAddress != "0")
        {
            var resources = new Resources();
            var style = (Style)resources.FindResource("StyleCrcs");
            var tabItem = new TabItem();
            tabItem.Style = style;
            tabItem.Header = cardName;
            TabCards.Items.Add(tabItem);              
        }
        return availableAddress;
    }
```

diferents styles have diferents textboxs.

I want change text in textbox for selected TabItem. I do something like this:

```
var item = ((TabItem)TabCards.SelectedItem).ContentTemplate;
```

When I do `item.` I dont see anything because probably i need cast.

But when i debug i can see the items from selected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBaq5.png)

How can i cast this or what should i do to could change text.

Comment: have you tied, just => var item = (TabItem)TabCards.SelectedItem ?

Comment: Yes, but i cant find this textBox name.